# Basic Webpack file & path resolving

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm new to Webpack and having some basic problems understanding how it resolves paths in conjunction with loaders. For example I am trying to load fonts using file-loader:

Folder structure

```
+-- index.html
+-- js
|   +-- index.js
|   +-- bundle.js
+-- css
|   +-- style.css
+-- elements
|   +-- fonts
|   |   +-- MyFont-Light.woff2
|   |   +-- MyFont-Light.woff
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
        filename: './js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('~elements/fonts/MyFont-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('~elements/fonts/MyFont-Light.woff') format('woff');
}
```

This gives me

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
>   ./elements/fonts/MyFont-Light.woff2

Am I going in the right direction here? What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just use `/elements/fonts/MyFont-Light.woff2`?

Comment: I'm working on a WP theme so that would resolve to the site's root instead of the theme's directory

Comment: If you need to resolve against site root, you could try setting `output.publicPath` so.